# Crystal Report showing Unwanted Space

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I have a sales invoice printing report using crystal, But if I have more than 22 item on 1 invoice the remaining item is on the second page. But in every second page I am getting a large space before starting the items...

Here see in my picture, first page is ok, but the second page details start only after the extra space. (from 23)

http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8505/8600841422_ef5dc8b225_m.jpg

Second page..

http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8247/8599744105_4487917838_m.jpg

If i have 3 pages the space increase more than second page. also there is a line like cont.... **_**  __

Hope you good guys can help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crystal Report Showing unnecessary lines or Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706391/crystal-report-showing-unnecessary-lines-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once.

I had inadvertently placed two static text fields on the control so that one overlapped the other by just a bit.

Moving the text fields so they abutted to each other, and NOT overlap, solved the problem.

Comment: see my crystal http://www.flickr.com/photos/94484260@N03/8600961642/in/photostream